# How to bookmark and send a class/activity to a bookmark page in android app?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app which consists of only text. Every page(xml) is different.
Now I want to make a bookmark page for the user to bookmark his/her favorites.
I succeeded making a bookmark page which is activated with a button on the home-screen, I also have a bookmark button on every text page, but I can't figure out how I can send or reveal my bookmarked page/text on the bookmark page.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether you bookmarked a page by using web service or db. Anyway i ll tell in DB. In DB concept you  will get a bookmark page like this

**just for ex:**

```
 public Cursor getAllContacts() {
 return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, null, null, null, null, "name");
}
```